# Efficiently drawing large number of polygons with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm currently using opengl to draw a several thousand polygons and it's running very slow. It takes apx 100 ms to draw 8000 polygons.

Here is some info about my set-up:

- I have each object in my 3d field set as a collection of 2d polygon planes, so a square would consist of 6, 4-vertex planes. So I do have access to each individual plane.
- I cannot guarantee that each polygon will have the same number of vertices
- I'm currently drawing as follows:

  ```
  for(allPlanes){
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
     for(allPointsInThePlane){
         glVertex(pointX,pointY,pointZ);
      }
    glEnd();
  }
  ```

This is much slower than I expected and I have looked into using glDrawElements() instead and breaking the polygon planes into triangles and using trianglefans or strips to draw them.

Im just looking for some advice on the most efficient way to do this, or any criticism on the way I'm approaching the drawing.

Comment: You are doing lots of OpenGL calls. Each call has some overhead, what makes the things slow for you. You must store all the data in a buffer, and use just a few calls to render everything. See @genpfault answer.

Answer (score 9):

[Triangulate](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html) everything and toss the triangles into a big [VA](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Arrays)/[VBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object).

**EDIT**: GLUtesselator wrapper:

```
struct TessContext
{
    ~TessContext()
    {
        for( size_t i = 0; i < combined.size(); ++i )
        {
            delete[] combined[i];
        }
    }

    vector< Eigen::Vector2d > pts;
    vector< GLdouble* > combined;
};

#define APIENTRY __stdcall

void APIENTRY tess_begin( GLenum type ) {}
void APIENTRY tess_edgeFlag( GLboolean flag ) {}
void APIENTRY tess_end() {}

void APIENTRY tess_vertex( void *data, TessContext* ctx )
{
    GLdouble* coord = (GLdouble*)data;
    ctx->pts.push_back( Eigen::Vector2d( coord[0], coord[1] ) );
}

void APIENTRY tess_combine( GLdouble coords[3], void *vertex_data[4], GLfloat weight[4], void **outData, TessContext* ctx )
{
    GLdouble* newVert = new GLdouble[3];
    ctx->combined.push_back( newVert );

    newVert[0] = coords[0];
    newVert[1] = coords[1];
    newVert[2] = coords[2];
    *outData = newVert;
}

template< typename Vec >
vector< Vec > Triangulate
    ( 
    const vector< Vec >& aSimplePolygon
    )
{
    vector< GLdouble > coords;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < aSimplePolygon.size(); ++i )
    {
        coords.push_back( aSimplePolygon[i].x() );
        coords.push_back( aSimplePolygon[i].y() );
        coords.push_back( 0 );
    }

    GLUtesselator* tess = gluNewTess();
    //gluTessProperty( tess, GLU_TESS_WINDING_RULE, GLU_TESS_WINDING_ODD );
    //gluTessProperty( tess, GLU_TESS_WINDING_RULE, GLU_TESS_WINDING_NONZERO );

    gluTessCallback( tess, GLU_TESS_BEGIN,          (GLvoid (APIENTRY *)())    tess_begin      );
    gluTessCallback( tess, GLU_TESS_EDGE_FLAG,      (GLvoid (APIENTRY *)())    tess_edgeFlag   );
    gluTessCallback( tess, GLU_TESS_VERTEX_DATA,    (GLvoid (APIENTRY *)())    tess_vertex     );
    gluTessCallback( tess, GLU_TESS_END,            (GLvoid (APIENTRY *)())    tess_end        );
    gluTessCallback( tess, GLU_TESS_COMBINE_DATA,   (GLvoid (APIENTRY *)())    tess_combine    );
    gluTessNormal( tess, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    TessContext ctx;

    gluTessBeginPolygon( tess, &ctx );
    gluTessBeginContour( tess );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < aSimplePolygon.size(); ++i )
    {
        gluTessVertex( tess, &coords[i*3], &coords[i*3] );
    }

    gluTessEndContour( tess );
    gluTessEndPolygon( tess );

    gluDeleteTess(tess);

    vector< Vec > ret( ctx.pts.size() );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < ret.size(); ++i )
    {
        ret[i].x() = ctx.pts[i].x();
        ret[i].y() = ctx.pts[i].y();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Uses [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) but not for anything interesting.

Answer (score 6):

[glDrawArrays()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml) or [glDrawElements()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) (or [glDrawRangeElements()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawRangeElements.xml)) are the preferred way, and also the only non-deprecated one. Immediate mode (your example) is the slowest and the least preferred method, useful mostly for OpenGL tutorials and (in my own experience) debugging. There are also `display lists`, "macros" for OpenGL that are only one step above using the immediate mode for drawing, and `vertex buffer objects (VBOs)`.

Any, except the immediate mode, should be sufficiently fast for your needs.

Comment: @aid, I'm running into trouble trying to use the glDrawArrays() function. I create an array of floats to use as the vertices of each of my planes. I enable GL_VERTEX_ARRAY and then assign a glVerterxPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,plane#array) for each of the arrays. So now I have a vertex pointer for each one of my planes. I then call glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0, ???) I'm confused as to what to do with the last parameter, would it be the total number of vertex pointers I have made?

Comment: The third parameter is the number of vertices to be drawn.

Answer (score 2):

Yes using Triangulation (which is a special case of tessellation) to compute the points and then drawing them is the preferred way (you used immediate mode which is deprecated)

The current graphics architecture uses [shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader)

So instead of sending a small set of vertices each time between the processor and GPU you should,

- Process all the vertices at once save it to a data structure and send this to the gpu
- Draw it at once (using glDraw*() functions),

This is faster because

- The entire array is calculated only once and is Retained in the data structure so that it can be reused
- The data is then sent completely to the GPU memory where further operations can be performed without any additional bottleneck of data transfers and associated overhead (by using Programmable shaders)